# Stored Procedure Returns Empty Values

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that performs a select statement in order to return user data to the session state on login.  So far, the stored procedure has only returned empty values when called by clicking the login button.  I have tested the stored procedure in Sql Mgmt Studio by running it after hard-coding an input username and achieved the desired results.  I have placed breakpoints in Visual Studio and found that while the username is being sent correctly from the textbox in which is was input, all parameters are being returned empty as "".  This leads me to believe the problem is something with formatting the input parameter, but I can't figure out what it is.  Any help is appreciated.

Here is my c# method:

```
public static User GetUser(int? id, string username)
{
 string SelectById = "spSelectUserById";
 string SelectByUsername = "spSelectUserByUsername";
 User u = new User();            
 string connstring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
 using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connstring))
 {
  SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
  cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
  if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(id.ToString()))
  {
   cmd = new SqlCommand(SelectByUsername, conn);
   cmd.Parameters.Add("@UserNameIn", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = username.ToString();
  }
  else if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(username))
  {
   cmd = new SqlCommand(SelectById, conn);
   cmd.Parameters.Add("@UserId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = id;
  }
   SqlParameter UserName = new SqlParameter();
   SqlParameter Password = new SqlParameter();
   SqlParameter FirstName = new SqlParameter();
   SqlParameter MiddleInitial = new SqlParameter();
   SqlParameter LastName = new SqlParameter();
   SqlParameter UserStar = new SqlParameter();
   SqlParameter UserRank = new SqlParameter();
   SqlParameter UserRankCode = new SqlParameter();
   SqlParameter Assignment = new SqlParameter();
   SqlParameter Shift = new SqlParameter();
   SqlParameter ContactPhone = new SqlParameter();
   SqlParameter PhoneType = new SqlParameter();
   SqlParameter Email = new SqlParameter();
   SqlParameter AssignmentId = new SqlParameter();
   SqlParameter ShiftId = new SqlParameter();
   UserName.ParameterName = "@UserName";
   Password.ParameterName = "@Password";
   FirstName.ParameterName = "@FirstName";
   MiddleInitial.ParameterName = "@MiddleInitial";
   LastName.ParameterName = "@LastName";
   UserStar.ParameterName = "@UserStar";
   UserRank.ParameterName = "@UserRank";
   UserRankCode.ParameterName = "@UserRankCode";
   Assignment.ParameterName = "@Assignment";
   Shift.ParameterName = "@Shift";
   ContactPhone.ParameterName = "@ContactPhone";
   PhoneType.ParameterName = "@PhoneType";
   Email.ParameterName = "@Email";
   AssignmentId.ParameterName = "AssignmentId";
   ShiftId.ParameterName = "ShiftId";
   UserName.SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar;
   Password.SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar;
   FirstName.SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar;
   MiddleInitial.SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar;
   LastName.SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar;
   UserStar.SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.Int;
   UserRank.SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar;
   UserRankCode.SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar;
   Assignment.SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar;
   Shift.SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar;
   ContactPhone.SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar;
   PhoneType.SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar;
   Email.SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar;
   AssignmentId.SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.Int;
   ShiftId.SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.Int;
   UserName.Size = 200;
   Password.Size = 200;
   FirstName.Size = 200;
   MiddleInitial.Size = 200;
   LastName.Size = 200;
   UserStar.Size = 200;
   UserRank.Size = 200;
   UserRankCode.Size = 200;
   UserRankId.Size = 200;
   Assignment.Size = 200;
   Shift.Size = 200;
   ContactPhone.Size = 200;
   PhoneType.Size = 200;
   Email.Size = 200;
   AssignmentId.Size = 200;
   ShiftId.Size = 200;
   UserName.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output;
   Password.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output;
   FirstName.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output;
   MiddleInitial.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output;
   LastName.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output;
   UserStar.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output;
   UserRank.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output;
   UserRankCode.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output;
   Assignment.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output;
   Shift.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output;
   ContactPhone.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output;
   PhoneType.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output;
   Email.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output;
   AssignmentId.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output;
   ShiftId.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output;
   cmd.Parameters.Add(UserName);
   cmd.Parameters.Add(Password);
   cmd.Parameters.Add(FirstName);
   cmd.Parameters.Add(MiddleInitial);
   cmd.Parameters.Add(LastName);
   cmd.Parameters.Add(UserStar);
   cmd.Parameters.Add(UserRank);
   cmd.Parameters.Add(UserRankCode);
   cmd.Parameters.Add(Assignment);
   cmd.Parameters.Add(Shift);
   cmd.Parameters.Add(ContactPhone);
   cmd.Parameters.Add(PhoneType);
   cmd.Parameters.Add(Email);
   cmd.Parameters.Add(AssignmentId);
   cmd.Parameters.Add(ShiftId);
   conn.Open();
   cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
   u.UserName = UserName.Value.ToString();
   u.Password = Password.Value.ToString();
   u.FirstName = FirstName.Value.ToString();
   u.MiddleInitial = MiddleInitial.Value.ToString();
   u.LastName = LastName.Value.ToString();
   u.UserStar = Convert.ToInt16(UserStar.Value);
   u.UserRank = UserRank.Value.ToString();
   u.UserRankCode = UserRankCode.Value.ToString();
   u.Assignment = Assignment.Value.ToString();
   u.AssignmentId = Convert.ToInt16(AssignmentId.Value);
   u.Shift = Shift.Value.ToString();
   u.ShiftId = Convert.ToInt16(ShiftId.Value.ToString());
   u.ContactPhone = ContactPhone.Value.ToString();
   u.PhoneType = PhoneType.Value.ToString();
   u.Email = Email.Value.ToString();
   return u;
  }
 }
```

Here is my stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spSelectUserByUsername
@UserNameIn         VARCHAR(MAX)    =   NULL                ,
@UserId             INT             =   NULL        OUTPUT  ,
@FirstName          VARCHAR(MAX)    =   NULL        OUTPUT  ,
@MiddleInitial      VARCHAR(MAX)    =   NULL        OUTPUT  ,
@LastName           VARCHAR(MAX)    =   NULL        OUTPUT  ,
@UserStar           INT             =   NULL        OUTPUT  ,
@UserRank           VARCHAR(MAX)    =   NULL        OUTPUT  ,
@UserRankCode       VARCHAR(MAX)    =   NULL        OUTPUT  ,
@UserRankId         INT             =   NULL        OUTPUT  ,
@Assignment         VARCHAR(MAX)    =   NULL        OUTPUT  ,
@AssignmentId       INT             =   NULL        OUTPUT  ,
@Shift              VARCHAR(MAX)    =   NULL        OUTPUT  ,
@ShiftId            INT             =   NULL        OUTPUT  ,   
@ContactPhone       VARCHAR(MAX)    =   NULL        OUTPUT  ,
@PhoneType          VARCHAR(MAX)    =   NULL        OUTPUT  ,
@Email              VARCHAR(MAX)    =   NULL        OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN

SELECT 
 @UserId            =   users.user_id                               ,
 @FirstName     =   users.first_name                            ,
 @LastName      =   users.last_name                             ,
 @MiddleInitial =   users.middle_initial                        ,
 @UserStar      =   users.user_star                             , 
 @UserRank      =   CONCAT(users.user_rank,' - ',ranks.title)   ,
 @UserRankCode  =   users.user_rank                             ,
 @UserRankId        =   ranks.id                                    ,
 @AssignmentId  =   users.assignment                            ,
 @Assignment        =   assignment.AssignmentName                   ,
 @ShiftId       =   users.regular_shift                         ,
 @Shift         =   s.DisplayName                               ,
 @ContactPhone  =   users.contact_phone                         ,
 @PhoneType     =   users.phone_type                            ,
 @Email         =   users.email                                     
FROM 
dbo.users
left JOIN
[shift] s   ON  users.regular_shift     =   s.shiftid
left JOIN
assignment  ON  users.assignment        =   assignment.AssignmentId
left JOIN
ranks       ON  users.user_rank         =   ranks.code
WHERE
users.username                          =   @UserNameIn
END
```

Comment: I really have to ask. Why don't you use a normal SqlDataReader or a DataAdapter.Fill?

Comment: This seems more complicated than just using a standard select statement in your stored procedure and manipulating the output, but you should note that when you use OUTPUT paramaters in a stored procedure, you need to run the stored procedure by specifying `OUTPUT` for the output paramaters (redundant, but necessary). (e.g. `EXEC myProc @output1=@myVar1 OUTPUT`)

Comment: @Steve - don't really have a good answer for you on that one.  I'm definitely still a beginning programmer so a lot of my stuff is probably a lot less efficient than it could be.  I have done a fair amount of work SqlDataReaders and SqlDataAdapters though and now that you mention it, that probably would be a lot easier than using output params.

Comment: Really, use a SqlDataReader and use the indexer to set the properties. Just one parameter required. A lot of examples are available here and everywhere on the net

Answer (score 0):

Change your procedure like the following, and use a SqlDataAdapter to get the result into a DataTable:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spSelectUserByUsername
@UserNameIn         VARCHAR(MAX)    =   NULL                ,

BEGIN

SELECT 
   users.user_id,
   users.first_name,
   users.last_name,
   users.middle_initial,
   users.user_star,
   CONCAT(users.user_rank,' - ',ranks.title),
   users.user_rank,
   ranks.id,
   users.assignment,
   assignment.AssignmentName,
   users.regular_shift,
   s.DisplayName,
   users.contact_phone,
   users.phone_type,
   users.email                                     
FROM  dbo.users
left JOIN [shift] s   ON  users.regular_shift = s.shiftid
left JOIN assignment  ON  users.assignment = assignment.AssignmentId
left JOIN ranks ON users.user_rank = ranks.code
WHERE users.username =  @UserNameIn
END
```

So that you can use the adapter to retrieve the data like this:

```
string connstring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
DataTable ResultTable = new DataTable();
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connstring))
{
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
    {
        cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.CommandText = "";
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@UserNameIn", SqlDbType.Int).Value = txtUserName.Text; // or what eve that supplay the username
        SqlDataAdapter sqlAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        sqlAdapter.Fill(ResultTable);
    }

}
```